# How do I apply the asterisk field in Wintitle?

Tags: autohotkey

Basically, I have a script that opens with Minecraft, and closes when minecraft is closed. However, the wintitle for minecraft changes every time a new launcher version or minecraft version is released. How can I make it simply check for a window starting with "Minecraft 1."?

Heres the code where these checks pop up:

```
IfWinNotExist, Minecraft 1.6.2
{
IfWinNotExist, Minecraft Launcher 1.2.1
{
    Run, Minecraft.exe
    WinWait, Minecraft, , 10
}
}

IfWinNotExist, Minecraft 1.6.2
{
    IfWinNotExist, Minecraft Launcher 1.2.1
    {
    ExitApp
    } 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [SetTitleMatchMode](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm). By default, window titles match when their beginning matches your parameter. Anyhow, I recommend you use [another identifier](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm) like `ahk_class` or AHK_L's `ahk_exe` or even `ahk_pid`. These are most probably safer to use and don't depend on the current version. You can find the class with window spy.

Comment: @MCL, please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [SetTitleMatchMode](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm). By default, window titles match when their beginning matches your parameter. Consequentially, a *wintitle* like `Minecraft` or `Minecraft 1.` would suffice.
Anyhow, I recommend you use [another identifier](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm) like `ahk_class` or AHK_L's `ahk_exe` or even `ahk_pid`. These are most probably safer to use and don't depend on the current version. You can find the class with window spy.

Comment: I tried with "Minecraft 1." and "Minecraft Launcher 1." and it doesnt work. Should i SetTitleMatchMode to slow?

 `   IfWinNotExist, Minecraft 1.
    {
 IfWinNotExist, Minecraft Launcher 1.
 {
  Run, Minecraft.exe
  WinWait, Minecraft, , 10
 }
    } `

Comment: @KevinDavidMartinez As I said, you'd be saving yourself a lot of trouble if you just go with another identifier.